# ASP.NET MVC 3 How to have multi-field create capability for Model with ICollection Property on Create view

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

Note: I'm using **MVC3+Razor, EF4, CF-CTP5**

1. How can you allow the view to have the ability to add multiple Address classes per Organization dynamically on the client, and bound strongly to the model on post?
2. How can you have the view parse values in the model if the (ModelState.IsValid == false) such that if you enter 3 addresses and post an invalid model, it re-populates the number addresses and with their appropriate values?

Here are my models:

```
public class Organization
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how you can have the Create action for Organization (/Organization/Create) handle the create like thus (such that addresses and phone numbers are part of the submitted model):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Organization organization)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Organizations.Add(organization);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", organization.Id);
    }

    return View(organization);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vaste :) 
This is just one of the way your requirement can be achieved and I am sure there are better than mine.

I am going to start from your second question:

> How can you have the view parse values
>   in the model if the
>   (ModelState.IsValid == false) such
>   that if you enter 3 addresses and post
>   an invalid model, it re-populates the
>   number addresses and with their
>   appropriate values?

If I correctly understand your request it looks very simple to me. The answer is simply ***code your view to render a Model class content*** and return the invalid model to the client exactly as you are doing in your `Create` action.

If your form (and its fields) have been decorated with the `ValidationSummary/ValidationMessage` html helpers, you are going to see also validation messages.

> 1. How can you allow the view to have the ability to add multiple Address
>      classes per Organization dynamically
>      on the client, and bound strongly to
>      the model on post?

You can have a main view showing Organization attributes and then have another view showing related addresses. Here you can place a hyperlink or a button that open a dialog for adding a new address object and then refresh the address list when done. At the same way you can have edit and delete buttons as icons on the list.

The address list is a piece of markup completely handled at client side that, to be correctly binded to the server side Model class should adhere to some simple naming rules for it's input attributes.

To make the Default Model Binder class bind correctly your form use the following snippet for your `Organization` class

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Id)
    @Html.ValidationSummary( true )
    <fieldset>
        <legend>My Organization</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor( model => model.Name )</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor( model => model.Name )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.Name )
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="container">
            <div>Address List</div>
            @foreach (Address a in Model.Addresses ) {
                Html.EditorFor(a);
            }
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:right;margin-top:14px;">
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

To be automatically bindable the resultant code for the form should look as the following

```
<form action="..." id="..." method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="Acme Corporation">

    <!-- markup for each address -->
    <input type="hidden" name="Addresses[0].Id" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="Addresses[0].Line1" value="Line 1">
    <input type="hidden" name="Addresses[0].Line2" value="Line 2">
    ... and so on...
</form>
```

having it's properties named as `Addresses[index].PropertyName`. 
If you add new addresses on the client it does'nt matter so much: as long as your code respect this rule you can have the default Model Binder do the job for you.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but with respect to question 1 I think you are looking for a ViewModel. Like this perhaps..

OrganizationViewModel.cs

```
public class OrganizationViewModel
{
  public OrganizationViewModel(Organization org, IList<Address> addresses)
     {
       this.Organization = org;
       this.Addresses = addresses
     }
     public Organization Organization {get;set;}
     public IList<Address> Addresses {get;set;}
}
```

OrganizationController.cs

```
public class OrganizationController : Controller
{
  private readonly IOrganizationService _organizationService: //or whatever method you use
  public OrganizationController(IOrganizationService orgService)
     {
       this._organizationService = orgService;
     }

   public ActionResult Item(int id)
     {
       var org = _organizationService.GetOrganizationById(id);
       var addresses = _organizationService.GetOrgAddressesByOrgId(id);
       return View(new OrganizationViewModel(program, addresses));
     }
}
```

Item.cshtml

```
@model OrganizationViewModel
<h1>@Model.Organization.Name</h1>
<ul>
@foreach(var a in Model.Addresses)
{
<li>@a.Line1</li>
<li>@a.Line2</li>}
</ul>
```

Before I try and answer number 2 maybe you should indicate whether I am correctly understanding question 1. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using LINQ to SQL. Now I'm trying to use Entity Framework instead, but it really makes everything more complicated. So I don't have a solution for you, but perhaps my L2S solution might help?

Using models generated from my database I could in my view do this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Contact.EmailAddresses.Count; ++i)
{
    <li>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Contact.EmailAddresses[i].EmailAddress)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Contact.EmailAddresses[i].EmailAddressID)
    </li>
}
```

I had a view model class:

```
class ContactViewModel
{
    Contact contact { get; set; }
}
```

This worked fine and in my controller action I got my Contact object with it's Contact.ContactEmailAddresses list filled just like I expected.

But with EF, I cannot use the [i] on the EmailAddresses property generated from the database anymore. The best I have come up with is:

```
@Html.TextBox("Contact.EmailAddresses[" + i + "].EmailAddress", Model.Contact.EmailAddresses.ElementAt(i).EmailAddress)
```